# Selectize is removing optgroup options

Tags: php, wordpress, selectize.js

I am using selectize (a select2.js alternative). When I am running selectize on my field with 2 optgroups, one of the optgroups disappears ＼（〇_ｏ）／

This is the HTML of the select field:
[image]

This is how it looks in view source:
[image]

It seems like the quotation symbol is causing it trouble because if I remove that value from the array before printing the values, the optgroup that disappears now appears. I do need however to have these symbols.

This is the PHP code that generates that HTML:

```
<select name="output_selected_columns[]" id="output_selected_columns" class="selectize" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="<?php echo sprintf( __( 'Columns of %s', 'excellico' ), $file1 ); ?>">
        <?php
        foreach( $Excellico_Files->get_file_left_header() as $key => $value ) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    
    <optgroup label="<?php echo sprintf( __( 'Columns of %s', 'excellico' ), $file2 ); ?>">
        <?php
        foreach( $Excellico_Files->get_file_right_header() as $key => $value ) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is how it looks: (missing File 1 optgroup)
[image]

I also tried to add `diacritics: true` to the selectize options object, didn't help.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The html output you provided is correct as can be seen.

```html
<select name="output_selected_columns[]" id="output_selected_columns" class="selectize" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="File 1">
    <option value="מוצר">מוצר</option>
    <option value="הזמנה">הזמנה</option>
    <option value="ת&quot;ז">ת"ז</option>
    <option value="שם מנוי">שם מנוי</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="File 2">
    <option value="מוצר">מוצר</option>
    <option value="הזמנה">הזמנה</option>
    <option value="ת&quot;ז">ת"ז</option>
    <option value="שם מנוי">שם מנוי</option>
    <option value="סטטוס תגמול">סטטוס תגמול</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

However it doesn't look it is generated by the php code you provided. Since that contains `'` and your html contains `"`

Try any of the following hopefully it will work

```php
<option value="<?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?></option>
```

Comment: Hello @IT goldman, I've revised my original post with the updated code, please look at the generated HTML and the quote symbol which I think is causing the issue here. That's the reason I tried `'` instead of `"`. It still doesn't work properly :/

Comment: can you paste the html as seen in the page source itself?

Comment: could `$Excellico_Files->get_file_left_header()` be empty?

Comment: Hey, I've added the view source to the original post. `$Excellico_Files->get_file_left_header()` is not empty, I've checked. Thanks

Comment: try posting a [mre]